# Replacing values or create a mask of tensor in tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of images and i want to create its binary mask in python.
That is replace values greater than zero with 255.
can anyone suggest or guide me suitably?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,
       `mask = tf.sign(images)*255` (if images is of values >=0)

For replacing values greater than a threshold, you can do:

```
thres = 10
cond = tf.greater(images, tf.ones(tf.shape(images))*thres)
mask = tf.where(cond, tf.ones(tf.shape(images))*255, tf.zeros(tf.shape(images)))
```

Comment: Are there any other options in tensorflow to replace the values other than zero..say for example if i need to replace values greater than 10

Answer (score 0):

If you have a boolean mask and want to apply it to an rgb image you can use `tf.where()`

```
image = tf.where(image_mask, image_rgb, tf.zeros_like(image_rgb))
```

This will black out pixels based on the mask.